Какой то отступ на начале верстки
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans+Caption:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <div class="wrapper"> -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <span class="logo"></span>
        <img src="../image/logo.jpg" class="logo">
        <div class="header-info">
          <span class="header-info__Main">Головна</span>
          <span class="header-info__Us">Про нас</span>
          <span class="header-info__Contacts">Контакти</span>
          <span class="header-info__Reviews">Відгуки</span>
        </div>
        <div class="header-connection">
          <div class="header-connection__back">Зворотній зв'язок</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>

в самом начале вёрстки добавил фреймворк "Bootstrap" и почему то появился отступ, который я не могу убрать

html код:
css код:
body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans Caption', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.wrapper {

}

/* -------------------------------------------------- */

.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {

}

.logo {
  height: 100%;
}

.header-info {
  
}

.header-info__Main {
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

.header-info__Us {
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

.header-info__Contacts {
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

.header-info__Reviews {

}


span с классом logo пустой уберите - он как бы тоже есть и влияет на justify-content: space-between;

У bootstrap есть .container (с ограничениями по ширине в точках) а есть .container-fluid который растягивает сетку на всю ширину. Может про это речь? (логотип тоже не правильно расположен)
примеры header https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/examples/headers/
